# [Unix][Shell Script] Copy all files from one folder to the other

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to create a bash shell script for daily cronjob.

The script is to copy all files with txt extension (including the sub-directories) from the folder "fromDir" to the folder "toDir".

It will also make the "toDir" directory if it doesnt exist.

I am trying to use tar here to compress the files and decompress after it moved to speed up the time it spent during the transfer, the target folder should have exactly the same structure as the original one.

```
#!/bin/bash -l

fromDir='c:/fromFolder/' ;
toDir='c:/toFolder/' ;
find $fromDir -maxdepth 3 -name '*.txt' -print |
tar zcvf - -T - |
mkdir -p -m 777 $toDir ;
cd $toDir && tar zxvf -
```

Comment: You can't use `;` between `|` and `tar`! Create your new directory before all, then use `-C` arg of `tar` instead of `cd`!

Comment: Got it! make perfect sense to me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you could use [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) you could try this:

```
rsync -av --include="*/" --include="*.txt" --exclude="*" ~/from/ ~/to/ --dry-run
```

This can be interpreted as for include every directory with `*.txt` and exclude anything else (the order is important)

The option `--dry-run` is just to print what will be done but no files will be copied.

Answer (score 1):

1st see my comment, then if you `tar` don't support `-C` argument (change to dir befor tar), you could try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

fromDir='c:/fromFolder/' ;
toDir='c:/toFolder/' ;
mkdir -p -m 777 $toDir ;
find $fromDir -maxdepth 3 -name '*.txt' -print |
tar zcf - -T - | (
    cd $toDir
    tar zxvf -
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help! it works perfectly!

Comment: Instead of `Thanks` comments, please consider **upvoting** and/or **accept** answer!